# How do I use 'git filter-branch' to update the SHA of a submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-filter-branch

Let's assume that I have two Git repositories, A and B. B is a submodule of A.

For the sake of simplicity, let's also assume that I have a magic function, `get_sha_B` that, given an SHA commit from A, returns the desired SHA commit of B.

How do I run filter-branch on repo A such that each commit of repo A is rewritten to point to the desired commit of repo B, as returned by `get_sha_B`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out! I'm going to answer my own question here:

I can use `git update-index` in conjunction with `git filter-branch --index-filter`.

Here's how to call update-index to modify the commit SHA of a submodule:

```
git update-index --cacheinfo 160000 88e6a302c42840440f9faac73f27efc6a3e0c1a6 pathto/mysubmodule
```

As best as I understand it, the 160000 is a magic number in Git used to identify a submodule.

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly something i was slowly moving towards. You just got me on top on how to do it